# Pythonic way to rewrite the following C++ string processing code

Tags: c++, python

Previous, I am having a C++ string processing code which is able to do this.

```
input -> Hello 12
output-> Hello

input -> Hello 12 World
output-> Hello World

input -> Hello12 World
output-> Hello World

input -> Hello12World
output-> HelloWorld
```

The following is the C++ code.

```
std::string Utils::toStringWithoutNumerical(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result;

    bool alreadyAppendSpace = false;
    for (int i = 0, length = str.length(); i < length; i++) {
        const char c = str.at(i);
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (false == alreadyAppendSpace) {
                result.append(1, c);
                alreadyAppendSpace = true;
            }
            continue;
        }
        result.append(1, c);
        alreadyAppendSpace = false;
    }

    return trim(result);
}
```

May I know in Python, what is the Pythonic way for implementing such functionality? Is regular expression able to achieve so?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this would be an ideal application of regular expressions. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: This reproduces more accurately what the C++ code does than the previous version.

```
s = re.sub(r"\d+", "", s)
s = re.sub(r"(\s)\s*", "\1", s)
```

In particular, if the first whitespace in a run of several whitespaces is a tab, it will preserve the tab.

Further Edit:  To replace by a space anyway, this works:

```
s = re.sub(r"\d+", "", s)
s = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s)
```

Comment: +1.  Was going to post a competing answer before your edit, but now you are correct!

Comment: Sorry. I retested my C++ code. Your previous solution is correct. Can you please repost your previous solution? I will edit back my test case.

Comment: Well, I reproduced what your example code does.  The code will collapse any run of consecutive whitespace characters, just leving the first one.  My Python code does the same.

Comment: My second version does essentially the same as the first one, except for the "first whitespace is not a space" issue.

Comment: But I tested run your current code, I saw a "smile icon" at the end of string. My guess is caused by "\1"? I think replace "\1" with " " will just fine

Comment: You can retrieve the old version by clicking on the link after "edited".

Comment: I prefer your current answer which is only 2 lines. I will use it for my own by replacing "\1" with " ". Can you edit the answer again, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5):

Python has a lot of built-in functions that can be very powerful when used together.

```
def RemoveNumeric(str):
    return ' '.join(str.translate(None, '0123456789').split())

>>> RemoveNumeric('Hello 12')
'Hello'
>>> RemoveNumeric('Hello 12 World')
'Hello World'
>>> RemoveNumeric('Hello12 World')
'Hello World'
>>> RemoveNumeric('Hello12World')
'HelloWorld'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub(r'[0-9]+', "", string)
```

Comment: No. It will fail at 2nd case. "Hello 12 World" will have 2 spaces in between, instead of the expected single space.

Comment: `" ".join( re.sub( r'[0-9]+', "", s ).split() )` Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.sub(r"(\s*)\d+(\s*)", lambda m: m.group(1) or m.group(2), string)
```

Breakdown:

- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- The parentheses are used to capture the whitespace.
- The replacement parameter is normally a string, but it can alternatively be a function which constructs the replacement dynamically.
- `lambda` is used to create an inline function which returns whichever of the two capture groups is non-empty. This preserves a space if there was whitespace and returns an empty string if there wasn't any.

Comment: Doesn't this have to be a raw string?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression answers are clearly the right way to do this.  But if you're interested in a way to do if you didn't have a regex engine, here's how:

```
class filterstate(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seenspace = False
    def include(self, c):
        isspace = c.isspace()
        if (not c.isdigit()) and (not (self.seenspace and isspace)):
            self.seenspace = isspace
            return True
        else:
            return False

def toStringWithoutNumerical(s):
    fs = filterstate()
    return ''.join((c for c in s if fs.include(c)))
```